# tcpdump only showing output after stopping it

Tags: tcpdump

I am trying to see if I get ping packets through one interface but tcpdump shows nothing. However, as soon as I stop it (Ctrl + C), all the packets appear and the summary looks good.

For example:

```
11:49:45.486887 IP 11.0.0.1 > 11.0.0.9: ICMP echo reply, id 13532, seq 1, length 64
```

And here the summary:

```
10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I normally see the traffic "live" but I don't understand why now it is hidden until I stop tcpdump. Can somebody point me to what might be happening?

Comment: add the -n flag to your tcpdump to remove DNS lookups, this can cause this problem is you have a slow / broken DNS server.

Comment: I tried: `tcpdump -ni qr-414d2474-1b icmp` but it did not fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want the `-l` or `-U` option. 
See the info in man page ...

```
   -l     Make  stdout  line buffered.  Useful if you want to see the data
          while capturing it.
          ...
          -U is similar to -l in its behavior, but it will cause output to
          be  ``packet-buffered'', so that the output is written to stdout
          at the end of each packet rather than at the end of  each  line;
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked! I should have read the manual but in other environments I am never adding the -l and it works. Do you know if this is something new?

Comment: Been there as long as I can remember. I suspect I just add it without thinking when displaying direct to terminal but mostly only needed for captures that produce little output.